# Function to return another function's body

Tags: f#

Is there a way in F# to create a function that takes any other function as its sole parameter and return that function's body text as the result?

For example:

```ml
let myFunc = 
    // Always equals 3!
    let x = 1 + 2

    // Print it to the console
    printfn "x = %i" x

let extractFunctionText f =
    ???

extractFunctionText myFunc
```

`extractFunctionText` should have a signature of `('a -> 'b) -> string` i.e. it will take any function as an input and returns a string. The string I'd like returned in the last line of specific example above is:

```
"""// Always equals 3!
let x = 1 + 2

// Print it to the console
printfn "x = %i" x"""
```

Apologies for any typos or naive questions: I'm a bit of a newb at this. I think that following links ([SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944668/f-quotations-traversing-into-function-calls-represented-by-a-value#answer-4945137) & [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233212.aspx#code-snippet-6)) get me quite close but I don't understand things well enough to finish the job

Comment: In general no, however consider *[F# Code Quotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233212.aspx)*.

Comment: Thanks I had already found that article. Is another option to read in the source file to a StreamReader and try to parse it directly?

Comment: What is your actual problem you are trying to solve - this seems a lot like the XY problem

Comment: @JohnPalmer It's a fair question. I deliberately omitted the context from the original question as I was (vainly) hoping for a simple solution.

Comment: @JohnPalmer The wider context is that I build time based models of business plans in Excel and am exploring moving to a coded language, in this instance F#. One of the things that's nice in Excel is that you can see the model logic and then numbers that result at the same time. I am working out if I can build a tool that shows the numbers of a generic model in a DataGrid (already done) and the text of each successive function (as a tooltip or other floating window). To do that I need to read the code of an arbitrary model at run-time, hence my problem.

Comment: What's the XY problem btw? Strike that; found [it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) after a simple Google search

Comment: You could probably do something with the debug info.  You might also be better off using scripts and the FSI rather than compiling.