# When are let bindings in code quotations replaced with their values?

Tags: f#

If I run the first example from MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233212.aspx) in the F# Interactive window, I get the expected output:

```
fun (x:System.Int32) -> x + 1
a + 1
let f = fun (x:System.Int32) -> x + 10 in f 10
```

But if I run it in the Main from my program, all let bindings are replaced by their constant values:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let a = 2

    // exprLambda has type "(int -> int)".
    let exprLambda = <@ fun x -> x + 1 @>
    // exprCall has type unit.
    let exprCall = <@ a + 1 @>

    println exprLambda
    println exprCall
    println <@@ let f x = x + 10 in f 10 @@>
```

Result:

```
fun (x:System.Int32) -> x + 1
2 + 1
let f = fun (x:System.Int32) -> x + 10 in f 10
```

Is this normal or a bug? Are the rules for this documented? What can I do to force it to the expected output?

**Edit:**
This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4945137/1872399) states `(Variables are automatically replaced with values if the variable is defined outside of the quotation).` but I couldn't find any mention of this elsewhere.

**Edit 2: What I really want to do**
This code (https://gist.github.com/0x53A/8848b04c2250364a3c22) goes into the catch-all case and fails with `not implemented:parseQuotation:Value (Variable "ax1")` (I expected it to go into `| Var(var) ->`) so not only constants known at compile-time, but also function parameters are expanded to their values.

**Edit 3:**
I ran the working version (https://gist.github.com/0x53A/53f45949db812bde5d97) under the debugger, and it looks like that one is actually the bug:
The quotation is `{Call (None, op_Addition, [PropertyGet (None, a, []), Value (1)])}` with`a` = `Program.a`, so this seems to be a side-effect of the fact that let bindings in modules are compiled into properties. If I am correct, I should maybe file a doc-bug at Microsoft...

Comment: What does your implementation of `println` look like? The example prints the name of variables as indicated by `| Var(var) -> printf "%s" var.Name`.  You seem to be substituting the value instead.

Comment: @JeffMercado It is the same implementation. I only moved the call to println into main. Complete: https://gist.github.com/0x53A/393517e955736ea7f4c5

Comment: Ok I see the same.  It look like putting it in a function makes a difference.  If the same snippet is in the top level, the variable is left intact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the problem with quoting of variables is that they escape their scope. That is, having a variable `foo` in your quotation does not really make any sense if you do not have any way to find out what does the `foo` variable refer to.

So, for example, the following is OK, because the variable `x` is defined by the lambda:

```
<@ fun x -> x @>
```

But if you have something like the following, it does not make sense to capture variable `x` because once the function returns, `x` is no longer in scope:

```
fun x -> <@ x @>
```

This is the same to the situation you're describing - top-level bindings become static members of a module and so those can be captured, but local variables are not available after the expression evaluates and so they are replaced by values. So, the general rules are:

- Accessing top-level bindings is quoted as getter of a static member
- Accessing variables defined inside the quotations is captured as variable access
- Accessing local variables of a function captures the value of the variable

There are definitely cases where being able to capture the variable name would be useful. One example that I really wanted to be able to do is to let people write for example:

```
plot(years, GDP)
```

The idea is that the `plot` function would get a quotation with variable names (which can then be used e.g. for plot axis). There is actually [an F# 4.0 change proposal](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharpLangDesign/blob/master/FSharp-4.0/AutoQuotationDesignAndSpec.md) that lets you do this.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation, and especially for the link to the F# 4 change.
I was initially confused by the MSDN example, because that never mentioned anywhere, that it has anything to do with toplevel / local scope.
If I have some time I will try the F# 4 preview to see if that solves my problem. ( The new ValueWithName pattern should)